# Can't setup ssh connection with bridge

Tags: ssh, networking, bridge, ping

I would like to set up an ssh connection to a device, which is bridge. It's a device to put between router and PC and the traffic just goes through. I don't have a ip-adress assigned to the bridge, so I can't ping any webaddress. Now I would like to set up an ssh connection but how can I get it working with a bridge?

This is what my bridge looks like:

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0D:B9:3E:D1:F4
          inet6 addr: fe80::60c4:28ff:fe56:541d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:816 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:58667 (57.2 KiB)  TX bytes:230 (230.0 B)
```

Comment: Normally you have other IP addresses associated with a bridge. In my home router, eth0 and wlan0 do not have associated IP addresses, however the bridge has. Otherwise, as you have noticed, it can be complicated working remotely.

Answer (score 1):

In order to ssh to the device it will need an IP address.  Since you already have the bridge setup it's not complicated to add an IP to the bridge device directly

```
ifconfig br0 (ip address) netmask (subnet mask)
```

Where "(ip address)" and "(subnet mask)" are replaced with appropriate values for your network.  Once you have that you can ssh to the device and setup the tunnel like you want.